# Bounded open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ as finite union of disjoint open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know that all open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as ***countable*** union of disjoint open intervals. However, I was hoping to restrict the case to ***finite*** union.

Can all bounded open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ be expressed as ***finite*** union of disjoint open intervals? If yes, how should the proof look like? If no, what are some counter-examples and is there anything we can say about the relationship between bounded open sets and finite union of disjoint open intervals?

Comment: Consider the union of all intervals of the form $(1/(2n+1), 1/(2n))$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the simple counter-example. Does it mean there is no way to relate open sets to finite union of disjoint intervals?

Comment: None that I know of.

Comment: @MartinR Got it, thank you!

Comment: The complement of the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is another example.

Comment: Given an open subset $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ we have that $U=\bigsqcup_{i\in I} C_i$ where $C_i$ are connected components of $U$. In this case connected components are open (since $U$ is locally connected). And connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval. And so there's at least one, rather simple relationship: $U$ can be written as a finite disjoint union of open intervals if and only if $U$ has finitely many connected components.

Comment: In *measure theory* there is a result where arbitrary measurable sets are approximated by finite unions of intervals.

Comment: @GEdgar Is there a name to this result or some resources I can read up more on?

Comment: See "Littlewood's three principles" ... https://math.gmu.edu/~dwalnut/teach/Math776/Spring11/776s11lec07_notes.pdf

Comment: @GEdgar This is only an approximation, right? So there will be some points, of measure 0, that will be excluded from this union.

Comment: That is why I said "approximated".  The extra points have small measure, but not $0$ measure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looking at the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), it's complement is

$$O:= \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \bigcup_{k=0}^{3^n-1} \left(\frac{3k+1}{3^{n+1}},\frac{3k+2}{3^{n+1}}\right)$$ which is open and bounded and needs infinitely many intervals (the decomposition into open intervals is unique, as these are exactly the connected components of the open set).